# Why my server with a public IP address can only display its web page to my local network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy

I can see the server's web page from my PC/phone on local network wifi.

I cannot see the server's web page using 3G on phone or home wifi.

I can ping to the server using my phone 3G.

Any suggestions?

====================================

The server web page error message is:

HTTP Error 504: Gateway Timeout

The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to complete the request.

Comment: Hard to say without a bit more information. Best guesses would be that 'your network' has a firewall or incoming HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can see the web page on local network, the IP address and the web server are correct configured.

Check subnet mask and default gateway settings of the web server. If malconfigured, the answer from server will not be sent back to you.